# Dropping Dataframe rows based on name

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe `df` where I am trying to drop all rows having `curv_typ` as `PYC_RT` or `YCIF_RT`.

```
    curv_typ   maturity    bonds  2015M06D19   2015M06D18   2015M06D17   \
0     PYC_RT       Y1    GBAAA        -0.24        -0.25        -0.23   
1     PYC_RT       Y1  GBA_AAA        -0.05        -0.05        -0.05   
2     PYC_RT      Y10    GBAAA         0.89         0.92         0.94
```

My code to do this is as follows. However, for some reason `df` turns out to be exactly the same as above after running the code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("ECB.tsv", sep="\t", index_col=False)
df[df["curv_typ"] != "PYC_RT"]
df[df["curv_typ"] != "YCIF_RT"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) and negate `~` the boolean condition for the mask:

```
In [76]:
df[~df['curv_typ'].isin(['PYC_RT', 'YCIF_RT'])]

Out[76]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [curv_typ, maturity, bonds, 2015M06D19, 2015M06D18, 2015M06D17]
Index: []
```

Note that this returns nothing on your sample dataset

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the resulting `DataFrame` to the original `DataFrame` (thus, over-writing it):

```
df = df[df["curv_typ"] != "PYC_RT"]
df = df[df["curv_typ"] != "YCIF_RT"]
```